# ¿Cómo resolver el problema java.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.mysql.jdbc.driver?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Mi código:

```
package u3_act3_propuesta_sistemainformatico;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class u3_act3_Inventario extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static Connection conn = null;
    static Statement st=null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;

    DefaultListModel modelo1 = new DefaultListModel();
    DefaultListModel modelo2 = new DefaultListModel();
    DefaultListModel modelo3= new DefaultListModel();
    DefaultListModel modelo4 = new DefaultListModel();
    DefaultListModel modelo5 = new DefaultListModel();
    DefaultListModel modelo6 = new DefaultListModel();

    static String bd="Tienda Don Chuy";
    static String login="Chuy";
    static String password="123456";
    static String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/"+bd;


    public static Connection Enlace(Connection conn) throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,password);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException c)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,c);
    }
    return conn;
}


/**
 * Creates new form u3_act3_Inventario
 */
public u3_act3_Inventario() {
    initComponents();
    Num.setModel (modelo1);
    Desc.setModel (modelo2);
    Marc.setModel (modelo3);
    Cant.setModel (modelo4);
    NInv.setModel (modelo5);
    Estado.setModel (modelo6);

    try
    {
        conn=Enlace(conn);
        st=conn.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery("select * from INVENTARIO");
        while (rs.next())
        {
            modelo1.addElement (rs.getString(1));
            modelo2.addElement (rs.getString(2));
            modelo3.addElement (rs.getString(3));
            modelo4.addElement (rs.getString(4));
            modelo5.addElement (rs.getString(5));
            modelo6.addElement (rs.getString(6));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException c)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error"+c.getMessage());
    }

}
```

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

Comment: Tiene que añadir la librería a su proyecto. `mysql-connector-java-x.x.x-bin.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Agrega la librería `mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar` (o la versión que tengas) a tu CLASSPATH de java:

```
java -classpath ".;mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar;otro-jar-1.0.jar" u3_act3_Inventario
```

Separa cada librería jar con `;` si estás usando windows.

Usa u3_act3_Inventario o la clase que tenga el methodo `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu servidor es tomcat, puedes copiar el archivo "***jar***" (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) en la carpeta ***"$CATALINA_HOME/lib"*** (https://juanalbertogt.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/instalar-tomcat-7-en-centos-rhel-o-fedora/). Después solo tienes que reiniciar el servidor y debería servir. Si aún no te sirve y estás programando un servidor web, podrías colocar el código fuente que hace todo el trabajo de consulta de la base de datos, en el archivo "jsp" o en otro archivo "jsp" incluido en él.

Comment: El siguiente es el código fuente que recorre una tabla de la base de datos: <%@ page session="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import = "app.sql.CSQL"%>
<%@ include file="Conexion.jsp" %>
<%  
    Connection Conexion = null;

    try {
        Conexion = Conectarse();
        String sConsulta = "select Cedula, Nombre from Usuarios order by Nombre asc";
        ResultSet rs = ConsultarSQL(Conexion, sConsulta);
%>
...

Comment: Código fuente del archivo donde se realiza la conexión a la BD: <%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%>
<%!
    Connection Conectarse() throws Exception
    {
        final String URL_SERVIDOR_BD = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BusquedaOfertasEmpleo";
        final String USUARIO_BD = "root";
        final String PASSWORD_BD = "unaContrasena";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL_SERVIDOR_BD, USUARIO_BD, PASSWORD_BD);
        return con;
    } // Connection Conectarse() throws Exception

Comment: Código fuente de la consulta SQL:     ResultSet ConsultarSQL(Connection con, String sSQL) throws Exception
    {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sSQL);
        return rs;
    } // ResultSet ConsultarSQL(Connection con, String sSQL) throws Exception

Comment: Hola @Manuel, los datos que has publicado en los comentarios colócalo en tu publicación. No utilice los comentarios para responder, son para sugerir mejoras o pedir aclaraciones o responder a otros usuarios.

Comment: En el siguiente enlace hago un mejor despliegue del código fuente: https://serverfault.com/questions/77388/tomcat-does-not-recognize-the-mysql-jar-library/1008587#1008587